# why 'port 8081 is not found' error is coming?

Tags: gitpod

[image: gitpod]

Why this error is coming when I am trying to run https://github.com/sbibek086/react-blog-app ?

Please anybody, can you guide me through this?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to open your workspace in local vscode for [port forwarding](https://www.gitpod.io/docs/configure/workspaces/ports#port-forwarding)?